# Is it possible to render HTML in Vaadin Tooltip component?

Tags: vaadin

Vaadin 23.3.2

I have an icon with a tooltip. Within the tooltip text I want to have some line breaks or put in a HTML link. How can I achieve this?

There used to be a setDescription where you could put in HTML in older versions but that seems to be gone.

Comment: Try Vaadin addon [https://vaadin.com/directory/component/tooltips4vaadin](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/tooltips4vaadin) It allows you to use component as tooltip content. Work fine with 23+ Vaadin version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not at the moment. There is a ticket about adding rich content or formatting support: https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/issues/4976, and another one proposing markdown support for Vaadin components in general: https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/issues/3551.

Support for interactive content like links will not be added to the tooltip for technical, incl. accessibility, reasons. This would instead require a different type of pop-up: a popover or toggletip, as proposed here: https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/issues/5328.

Please upvote (with a thumbs-up reaction to the OP) any tickets you would like to see happen.